# NSFont convert font to bold or italic

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsfont

I'm using the following code to change a font to bold on iOS.

```
UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = [UIFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithName:font.fontName size:font.pointSize];     
UIFontDescriptor *styleDescriptor = [fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:[fontDescriptor symbolicTraits] | UIFontDescriptorTraitBold];
UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:styleDescriptor size:0];
```

I'm trying to do the equivalent thing on Mac OS X.  I tried this but it's picking a bolder font than the iOS code.

```
NSFont *boldFont = [[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] convertFont:font toHaveTrait:NSFontBoldTrait];
```

I want the Mac code to behave exactly like the iOS code and pick the same bold font.

Comment: Perhaps that's the only bold face of that font on the system. Use the Font Book app to check.

Comment: I'm using `Avenir Next Medium` for the standard font.  On iOS it selects `Avenir Next Demi Bold` for the bold font but on OS X it selects `Avenir Next Bold`.  Both variations are present on iOS and OS X.

Comment: matt is right.  That's because Demi Bold is not the bold trait for the Avenir Next font family on OS X.  If you really want to set Demi Bold, then you have to specifically select its typeface.

Comment: Ok.  How can I be more specific in selecting the desired weight using `NSFontManager`?

Comment: Try `-convertWeight:ofFont:`.

Comment: That worked perfect!